# How to show cutom plugin data inside wordpress dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am new to wordpress plugin development and I have a created a simple contact form plugin which takes name, email, and message as input, I just want to show the data saved in the form in the wordpress dashboard.

Here's a brief overview of what I've done so far:

1- Created a contact form using the add_shortcode function.

2- Handled form submissions and saved the data using wp_insert_post.

3- Set up a custom post type for form submissions and customized the dashboard view.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

 if(!class_exists('DemoPlugin'))
 {
    class DemoPlugin
    {
        public function __construct()
        {   
            //Create custom post type
            add_action('init', [$this, 'create_custom_post_type']);
            // add_action('init', [$this, 'list_all_shortcodes']);

            //Add Shortcode
            add_shortcode('demo_plugin_contact', [$this, 'demo_plugin_contact']);

            //Register REST API
            add_action('rest_api_init', [$this, 'register_rest_api']);
        }

        public function create_custom_post_type()
        {
            $args = [
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'custom-fields'],
                'exclude_from_search' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => false,
                'capability' => 'manage_options',
                'labels' => [
                    'name' => 'Contact Form(Demo-Plugin)',
                    'singular_name' => 'Contact Form Entry',
                    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-document',
                ]
            ];

            register_post_type('demo-plugin', $args);
        }

      
        public function register_rest_api()
        {
            register_rest_route('demo-plugin-form/v1', 'send-email', [
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => [$this, 'handle_contact_form']
            ]);
        }

        public function handle_contact_form($data)
        {   
            $headers = $data->get_headers();
            $params = $data->get_params();
            $nonce = $headers['x_wp_nonce'][0];

            if(!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'wp_rest'))
            {
                return new WP_REST_Response('Message not sent', 422);
            }

            $name = sanitize_text_field($params['name']);
            $email = sanitize_email($params['email']);
            $message = sanitize_text_field($params['message']);

            $post_id = wp_insert_post([
                'post_type' => 'demo-plugin',
                'post_title' => "Contact Enquiry from $email",
                'post_content' => "$email",
                'post_status' => 'publish',
            ]);

            if($post_id)
            { 
                return new WP_REST_Response('Form Submitted successfully', 200);
            }
        }
    }
 }

 new DemoPlugin();
```